# Textbox value returns empty in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I am new to angularjs. I have some issues in getting the value of the textbox. And it only returns an empty string, which I think because I declare each of the model equal to "". Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<form name="account" ng-submit="update_account(account.$submitted && account.$valid)" novalidate>
      <input required placeholder="{{placeholderForName}}" name="name" ng-model="name" type="text">
       <input required placeholder="{{placeholderForUname}}" name="uname" ng-model="uname" type="text">
       <input required placeholder="{{placeholderForPassw}}" name="passw" ng-model="passw" type="password">
      <button type="submit">Save!</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.name = "";
$scope.uname = "";
$scope.passw = "";

$scope.account_update = function(isValid){
    if(isValid){

        $http.post('query?action=tnoucca_etadpu',{
            'name': $scope.name,
            'uname': $scope.uname,
            'passw': $scope.passw
        })
        .then(function(response){

            alert(response.data); // alerts empty string

        })
        .catch(function(response){
            $scope.showToast("SYS_ERROR: " + response.data);
        });

    }
};
```

**PHP**

```
if ($action == "tnoucca_etadpu") {

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $name = $data->name;
    $uname = $data->uname;
    $pw = $data->passw;

    echo $name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong function name in `ng-submit="update_update(account.$submitted && account.$valid)"` instead of `$scope.account_update`

see example plnkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7T8O1lD4xde4DxPYxZLC?p=preview)

Else nothing is wrong with your angular code.

In Addition 
     you can use :`if($scope.account.$valid){}` instead of `if(isValid){}` and don't need to pass any value.